# -bash Termilan mac

Tags: mysql

Quise habilitar el comando MySql en la terminal de Mac, no tuve éxito, pero ahora cada que abro la terminal aparece esto:

Last login: Wed Jun  6 10:36:08 on ttys000
-bash: export: `=/Application/MAMP/Library/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier
MacBook-Air-de-Nora:~ noraprogramadora$

¿Cómo puedo salirme de ahí?

Comment: ser un error de ruta, o es un error de autentificación, o no sé nada

Comment: eso mismo pense, pero no se si afecte a la funcionalidad correcta de la terminal...

Comment: ¿Has probado con sudo? También intente formatear su código, no es mega legible.

Comment: el problema es que no se bien como usar sudo

Comment: ...
MacBook-Air-de-Nora:~ noraprogramadora$ -u user
-bash: -u: command not found
MacBook-Air-de-Nora:~ noraprogramadora$ -h
-bash: -h: command not found
MacBook-Air-de-Nora:~ noraprogramadora$

Comment: Debes utilisar sudo al principio y luego haz tu pedido

Comment: si lo puse, pero aqui ya no me dejaba comentarlo porque me pasaba los caràcteres

Comment: `MacBook-Air-de-Nora:~ noraprogramadora$ sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
            [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] file
            ...
MacBook-Air-de-Nora:~ noraprogramadora$`

Comment: Por favor, formatea el código con ` `código` `

Comment: @Marine1 listo.

Comment: No estoy seguro de la respuesta correcta, Si alguna vez alguien te responde aqui, pregunta [sobre el stackoverflow para Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) o equivalentes en la red.